# Exchange Server. Move Item operation. How to map new items to the moved ones?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In my mail app I'm moving messages between folders by using [MoveItem operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/moveitem-operation). When you move messages their ids are changed. In the response I'm receiving the new message ids. But the old ones are missing. And this is a big problem.

I have no idea how to map a new message id to an old one and can't update messages in my database with the new ids. Seems like I don't understand something simple. What's the point of returning new ids if you have no idea what message each one belongs to?

Am I supposed to rely on the order of response messages? If so can you please give me a link to the corresponding piece of EWS documentation?

Or am I supposed to perform synchronization of mailboxes every time I move more than one message?

Comment: Do you want to have on the moved `Item` the new `ItemId` and the old one?

Comment: I want to update the items in my database with the new ids. I have the items, I have the new ids, but I don't to know how to map one to another because there's no relation between them. Do you understand?

Comment: Do you have code written? Or how do you move the items?

Comment: I’m making xml with MoveItem operation and send this xml in http request to Exchange server

Comment: Ok, this means you're not using the managed API, I'm not familiar with the  web service. Anyway: I would [create a custom extended property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633654(v=exchg.80)) and set it to the `ItemId` of the `Item` to be moved. Then [update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.update?view=exchange-ews-api) the `Item` in order to transfer the new state to the server. After you moved the `Item` you can read the custom property. Then you have the old and the new `ItemId`.

Comment: I’m confused about your question.
I don’t understand why you mapping the itemID to another ID?
when you move or copy an email message into a different folder, a new item is created in the new folder with a unique item ID, and the original message is deleted.
You can get new items with the new ID.
please see the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: @Evanzheng this is true. I know this all. But I need to map one to another because I need to update messages in my database. Or should I delete them and get the new ones? This leads to a different problem. Moving items and getting the new ones takes time. But I need to make changes in my app instantly. If user moves messages to a different folder they have to be there instantly and user should see them there without seeing "Please wait, we are moving the messages". Of course I can move my local messages then get the new ones and then delete the ones I've moved. But this is cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

When you used MoveItems you would have passed in an array of ItemId's and what you get back as a result is an Array of  objects.

The order of the items in the Response collection matches the order in your request so element 1 of the response represents the results of the element 1 request. So you can just map them this way.

However your response logic should be more complex to deal with issues where half of your request being executed okay while x% failed because of throttling etc (so check the response status of each request) or getting a 501 mid move where you could get into an unknown state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Glen! Is it mentioned somewhere in the Exchange docs that the order of ids in the response matches the order of ids in the request? Also I assume that this rule applies to all the Exchange operations not only MoveItem, right?